# React Navigation v5: How to navigate using redux thunk/redux saga?

Tags: react-native, react-redux, redux-saga, redux-thunk, react-navigation-v5

How can I navigate the screen in [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) in Redux-Saga and Redux-Thunk? Is it possible to get access to the [navigation context](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-actions) in sagas or thunk?

For example in redux-thunk

```
import { StackActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

dispatch(StackActions.replace('Profile', {
    user: 'jane',
}))
```

Or, in redux-sagas

```
import { StackActions } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { put } from 'redux-saga/effects';

yield put(StackActions.replace('Profile', {
    user: 'jane',
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `'@react-navigation/compat'` library.

```
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createCompatNavigatorFactory } from '@react-navigation/compat';
const RootStack = createCompatNavigatorFactory(createStackNavigator)(
  {
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
    Profile: { screen: ProfileScreen },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Profile',
  }
);

import { StackActions } from '@react-navigation/compat';

dispatch(StackActions.replace('Profile', {
    user: 'jane',
}))
```

For more information please check this [link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/compatibility/)

Answer (score 0):

In Summary (snippets copied from the v5 doc)

You can get access to the root navigation object through a ref and pass it to the RootNavigation which you will use later to navigate.

```js
// App.js

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { navigationRef } from './RootNavigation';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>{/* ... */}</NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Define RootNavigation, which is a simple module with functions that dispatch user-defined navigation actions.

```js
// RootNavigation.js

import * as React from 'react';

export const navigationRef = React.createRef();

export function navigate(name, params) {
  navigationRef.current?.navigate(name, params);
}

// add other navigation functions that you need and export them
```

Then, in any of your javascript modules, just import the RootNavigation and call functions which you exported from it.

```js
// any js module
import * as RootNavigation from './path/to/RootNavigation.js';

// ...

RootNavigation.navigate('ChatScreen', { userName: 'Lucy' });
```

The Official React-Navigation v5 Doc.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/5.x/navigating-without-navigation-prop/